# PHP group keys in array with multiple values

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, associative-array

I've got an array like this:

```
$sendemail= array(
  'apple@yahoo.com' => '123456781234567',
  'apple@yahoo.com' => '013881002296968',
  'cherry@yahoo.com' => '3553220865206561',
  'orange@yahoo.com' => '358805051217453',
  'apple@yahoo.com' => '357998054217777',
  'cherry@yahoo.com' => '013881002296968',
);
```

I would like to have an output like this:

```
'apple@yahoo.com' => 123456781234567, 013881002296968, 357998054217777
'cherry@yahoo.com' => 3553220865206561, 013881002296968
'orange@yahoo.com' => 358805051217453
```

to be able to use the keys as email address and the values as my email's buddy

```
$email= 'apple@yahoo.com';
$body= '123456781234567, 013881002296968, 357998054217777';
mail($email, 'Your codes', $body);
```

And the same for the other email addresses.

PLEASE NOTE that 2 keys might have the same values which is fine (e.g. apple@yahoo.com and cherry@yahoo.com have the same values; the value will be sent to both of them)

I used this 'for loop' but didn't work. first of all I cant group them based on email addresses, second of all the same values will not be assigned to the other email addresses; like '013881002296968' which should be shared with apple@yahoo.com and cherry@yahoo.com

```
$sendmail= array(
  '123456781234567' => 'apple@yahoo.com',
  '013881002296968' => 'apple@yahoo.com',
  '3553220865206561' => 'cherry@yahoo.com',
  '358805051217453' => 'orange@yahoo.com',
  '357998054217777' => 'apple@yahoo.com',
  '013881002296968' => 'cherry@yahoo.com',
);
$out = array();
foreach($sendmail as $key=>$value)
    if(array_key_exists($value, $out)) {
         $out[$value][] = $key;
    }
    else {
         $out[$value] = array($key);
    }
```

Output

```
array (
  'apple@yahoo.com' => 
  array (
    0 => 123456781234567,
    1 => 013881002296968,
    2 => 357998054217777,
  ),
  'cherry@yahoo.com' => 
  array (
    0 => 3553220865206561,
  ),
  'orange@yahoo.com' => 
  array (
    0 => 358805051217453,
  ),
)
```

Comment: You can't have multiple same keys in an array, Likewise you have in `$sendemail`.

Comment: Yeah it would have to be 0=>'apple@yahoo.com' and then 1=>'apple@yahoo.com' to work. Can you please post the contents of `print_r($sendemail)` for us? It will help reveal what's really going on

Comment: I did a `print_r($sendemail)` and this is what I got: ```Array
(
    [apple@yahoo.com] => 357998054217777
    [cherry@yahoo.com] => 013881002296968
    [orange@yahoo.com] => 358805051217453
)```

Comment: Please restructure your input array (edit your question) so that we can help you.  http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/643b1597d454920debaf2ca626fca6ec92faa265

Comment: @PersianHero Are you going to update your question / input array? In its current state, it cannot be solved properly and may get closed.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative to Kris' method that has less iterations, but more conditionals:

Input:

```
$sendmail= array(
  '123456781234567' => 'apple@yahoo.com',
  '013881002296968' => 'apple@yahoo.com',
  '3553220865206561' => 'cherry@yahoo.com',
  '358805051217453' => 'orange@yahoo.com',
  '357998054217777' => 'apple@yahoo.com',
  '013881002296968' => 'cherry@yahoo.com',
);
```

Method:

```
foreach($sendmail as $k=>$v){
    if(!isset($out[$v])){$out[$v]='';}  // initialize new element with empty string
    $out[$v].=($out[$v]?',':'').$k;     // concat the values with conditional comma
}
var_export($out);
```

Output:

```
array (
  'apple@yahoo.com' => '123456781234567,357998054217777',
  'cherry@yahoo.com' => '013881002296968,3553220865206561',
  'orange@yahoo.com' => '358805051217453',
)
```

Comment: Yeah, as you can see, '013881002296968' should be in apple@yahoo.com as well but it's not.

Comment: @PersianHero Oh, I see that now.  You have an error in your input array.  You can't duplicate keys and retain all values.  That's not how arrays work.  Please provide a valid/working input array structure for us to play with.

Comment: @PersianHero Your question may become abandoned (permanently unresolved) unless you update your question.  If you update it, please ping me so I can come back and provide a working answer.  All questions on SO should receive some sort of resolution, let's work toward resolution on this question.

Answer (score 0):

Use implode on the element of your result array. [live demo](https://eval.in/793494)

```
foreach($sendmail as $key=>$value) {
    $out[$value][] = $key;
}
$out = array_map(function($v){return implode(',', $v);}, $out);
```